# Removing local notification on ios react native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-push-notification

Im developing an app which is connected to a bluetooth device. If the device is disconnected the user receives a push notification that the device is disconnected. This works fine on both android and iOS with this [library](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification).

If the application reconnects, then i want to remove the notification. This works fine on android, but does not remove the notification on iOS.

Here is the code for creating notification:

```
export const pushNotification = (title: string, message: string) => {
  PushNotification.localNotification({
    channelId: 'channel',
    title: title,
    message: message,
    id: '1',
  });
};

export const configurePushNotification = () => {
  PushNotification.configure({
    requestPermissions: true,
  });
};

export const createChannelForPushNotification = () => {
  PushNotification.createChannel(
    {
      channelId: 'channel',
      channelName: 'Push Notification Channel',
      channelDescription: 'A channel to send push notifications',
      soundName: 'default',
      importance: Importance.HIGH,
      vibrate: true,
    },
    (created) => console.log(`createChannel returned '${created}'`),
  );
};
```

I use the code below to remove the notification, which works fine on android.

```
 PushNotification.cancelLocalNotification('1');
```

Any suggestions as to why it is not removing local notification on iOS?